# Copying raw html from a file into a razor page, in aspnet core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm moving an existing ASP.NET/MVC app to aspnet core, and there's a bit where I'm not sure of the cleanest solution.

The issue is that we have a shared view that is called from a number of controllers. There's a chunk of html that is loaded from a file by the controller, and then is inserted into the page by the view using @Html.Raw().

The existing code in .NET Framework is using an extension method on Controller to get the contents of the file:

```
public static class ControllerExtension
{
    public static string GetContents(this Controller controller, string path)
    {
        var filepath = controller.Server.MapPath(path);
        var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
        return contents;
    }
}
```

This, of course, does not work in aspnet core.  There is no Server.MapPath().

Googling around I found that the recommended approach is to use IWebHostEnvironment. I could do that - inject it into my controller, and pass it to my GetContents() extension, but that's starting to have a bit of a whiff about it.

So I'm wondering, is there some other mechanism for doing the basic task?

Assume I have a number of files in a directory under wwwroot, each containing plain html.

What would be the cleanest way to have a controller include the contents of one of these files in a .cshtml view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the `WebRootPath` property of the environment to get to wwwroot and use relative paths from there. Example:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        this.environment = environment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(environment));
    }

    public IActionResult GetContents(string path)
    {
        var contentPath = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, path);
        var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentPath);

        // Do something with content and return
    }
}
```

You would of course want more checks to validate the user-provided path before attempting to read the file. Also, would likely make this async unless you cache the content and normally serve the memory-cached data.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, pretty much, except that it feels like there should be some functionality in aspnet core to manage it directly.

Comment: If you just want to serve static html files, that would be through `UseStaticFiles()`. Given that this amounts to 2 lines of code, curious what it "feels like there should be"?

Comment: I want to embed html content from one of several files in a view.

Is there not an html helper that will load raw html from a file?